# SqlConnection string

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a portable connection string with a service-based database.

If I use

```
C:\Users\X\Desktop\C# Projects\Windows Form Applications\PortableConnectionString\PortableConnectionString\BazaDate.mdf
```

and not `|DataDirectory|BazaDate.mdf`, it works.

What can I do to make it portable?

```cs
SqlConnection conn= new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BazaDate.mdf;Integrated Security=True;");
conn.Open();
```

Comment: This isn't a right practice.  you are exposing your filename/path.

Answer (score 2):

`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]` is the full path of your executable, thus:

```
string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);
string connStr = $@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename={appPath}\BazaDate.mdf;Integrated Security=True;";

var conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
conn.Open();
```